# How to migrate from one backing store to another

Tags: javers

I need to figure out a way to migrate our Javers audit data from DocumentDB to another independent repository than our domain data.

Does javers currently have any mechanism we can use to take our existing data and insert it properly into a second DB without having to manually map the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no migration tool. There are two javers' collections in MongoDB: `jv_snapshots` and `jv_head_id`, it's easy to copy them manually.